# How to give access my WebView for use browse file?

Tags: xamarin.forms, webview

I use a WebView on my Xamarin app, and I use it without any problem. but I can't use browse file on my phone for select file. I click button but I don't see any action. that is work on my web site, but I can't use it on my phone app.

[On my web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4kj0.png)

Comment: Please search before posting.  This has been discussed many times

Comment: @Jason , I search and find result for question, but I got now another problem: Java.Lang.ClassCastException: 'android.net.Uri$HierarchicalUri cannot be cast to android.net.Uri[]'
you have any solution for this problem?

Comment: If you have a new problem you should ask a new question and include the relevant code, not just an error message without any context.  Please read [ask]

Comment: @Jason , okay thanks you. so now come this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75476395/xamarin-forms-java-lang-classcastexception-android-net-urihierarchicaluri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check this code and use the `new Uri[]`.

```
  protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent intent)
    {
        if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE)
        {

            if (null == mUploadMessage) return;
            Android.Net.Uri result = intent.Data;
            mUploadMessage.OnReceiveValue(new Uri[] { result });
            mUploadMessage = null;
        }
    }
```