# Xamarin. Forms => Java.Lang.ClassCastException: 'android.net.Uri$HierarchicalUri cannot be cast to android.net.Uri[]'

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, webview

I use  in my web view and use this web view in my Xamarin Forms app, I enable use input in Xamarin Forms and file browser opened on my phone, but after I select any file, I got this Exception:
Java.Lang.ClassCastException: 'android.net.Uri$HierarchicalUri cannot be cast to android.net.Uri[]';

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent intent)
        {
            if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE)
            {
                if (null == mUploadCallbackAboveL)
                    return;
                Java.Lang.Object result = intent == null || resultCode != Result.Ok
                    ? null
                    : intent.Data;
                mUploadCallbackAboveL.OnReceiveValue(result);
                mUploadCallbackAboveL = null;
            }
        }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4nrU.png)

Comment: it sounds like `OnReceiveValue` expects an array of objects, not a single object

Comment: You can debug to see the value of the `intent`. Just as Jason said, `OnReceiveValue` expects an array of objects, not a single object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I fix that with this code:

```
    protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent intent)
    {
        if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE)
        {
            if (resultCode == Result.Ok)
            {
                Android.Net.Uri result = intent.Data ?? ImageUri;
                if (UploadCallbackAboveL != null)
                {
                    UploadCallbackAboveL.OnReceiveValue(new Android.Net.Uri[] { result });
                }
            }
            else
            {
                UploadCallbackAboveL.OnReceiveValue(null);
            }
            UploadCallbackAboveL = null;
        }
        else
        {
            base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You answer your own question, and if you consider that is the solution so be it.
But you should not title your question with code, it will be so difficult to find someone to help you.
Consider change your question title now that you already have the answer, to help people with a similar situation.